# Chrome unable to expand ssrs reports in browser like IE and mozilla

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services

Please advice how to grow columns in chrome browser for ssrs reports

Answer (score 0):

I the chrome extension IEtab, this solves all chrome related issues in ssrs for me. http://www.ietab.net/